# How many ways for a beetle to move from bottom left corner to upper right corner in a 6 x 6 grid if it must be done in 14 steps only?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics, path-connected

Note:  We allow all four directions (up, down, right, left but no diagonal)

The 6 x 6 grid is composed of 7 horizontal  lines and 7 vertical lines. We are to calculate how many 14 steps paths are possible where it never returns to the same intersecting point.

The answer given is

$$C(12, 8)  \times C(8,7) \times (6/8) \times 2 = 5940$$

where $C(n,r)$ is here is the Binomial Coefficient.

I cannot seem to figure out how this counting was done.
Can somebody provide me with the explanation regarding how this counting argument was done please? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear: the beetle moves on the $7\times7$ grid points, not the $6\times6$ squares, is that correct?

Comment: @youthdoo Re: editing - there are various notations for binomial coefficients.  Some people prefer one, some people prefer another.  Please do not change the OP's choice unless it is actually wrong.

Comment: @David But from what's shown, the op does not use $\rm\LaTeX$ at all. The point is not what form the binomial coefficients are expressed in, but it is better to use $\rm\LaTeX$ for formulae. This is also why I edited, as you can see from the reason I wrote.

Comment: Is C(m,n) really one of the correct notations? At least, change all the x into `\times`...

Comment: @youthdoo You can add LaTeX without changing the actual notation.  And yes, $C(m,n)$ is very common, so is $\binom mn$ and $C^m_n$.  It's just a matter of politeness: I do not think you would be very happy if someone changed your posts just because they thought it would look better a different way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how that formula was obtained but here is another argument which gives the same result numerically.  We generalise to finding paths of length $m+n+2$ on an $m\times n$ grid from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$.

It is not hard to see that the path must consist of one of the following mutually exclusive possibilities:

- $m-2$ single moves right, $n+1$ single moves up, $1$ sequence of three moves right-down-right;
- $m+1$ single moves right, $n-2$ single moves up, $1$ sequence of three moves up-left-up.

To count the first type we begin by arranging $m-2$ letters R and $n+2$ letters U: this can be done in $C(m+n,m-2)$ ways.  Then we replace one of the letters U by RDR: this can be done for any of the $n+2$ letters U except the first or last, so there are $n$ options.  A similar argument for the second case gives the total number of paths as
$$n\binom{m+n}{m-2}+m\binom{m+n}{n-2}\ .$$
If $m=n$ this is
$$2m\binom{2m}{m-2}\ ,$$
and in particular for the $6\times6$ grid it is
$$12\binom{12}{4}=5940\ .$$

Comment: It does not say from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$? I thought is was moving aimlessly around.

Comment: @youthdoo title says bottom left to upper right.

Comment: Oh David, that is so brilliant!
I understand it and never found such an explanation elsewhere and you saved me from what has been a few days of trying to solve without any success. And this general method is very useful in more situations, ah so helpful indeed. God Bless

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to explain the given calculation, though I do feel it's a rather awkward way to tackle the problem.

Since moving from the bottom left to the top right in a 6x6 grid would require a minimum of 12 steps, a 14-step sequence of movements must consist of 6 right (R) steps, 6 up(U) steps, plus either one left (L) and one additional right, or one down (D) and one additional up. Since we're not allowed to return to a previous point, we cannot have L & R or U & D appear consecutively, which means that the L would have to be 'sandwiched' between two U's or the D would be between two R's.

Let's assume that we're looking at the former case, with an L and an additional R. Then we can say the path must consist of 12 'blocks': the seven R's, four of the six U's, plus the ULU combination. We want to count the arrangements of these 12 blocks, subject to one additional condition mentioned below.

We start by choosing the eight positions for the R & ULU blocks; this can be done in

$$\binom{12}{8}$$

ways. Then we choose the positions of the seven R's, leaving the ULU in whichever of the eight spots remains; that gives us

$$\binom{12}{8} \times \binom{8}{7}$$

However, note that we cannot have the ULU before or after all the R steps, as we have to move right at least once before we can move left, and at least once after we move left (otherwise the left step would be coming from outside the grid.) So we have to eliminate the $\frac{2}{8}$ of the sequences where ULU comes first or last, leaving us

$$\binom{12}{8} \times \binom{8}{7} \times \frac{6}{8}$$

The four remaining U's would go in the last four empty spots, so they add nothing to the count. Finally we have to account for the possibility of having RDR instead of ULU, so we double our count to arrive at

$$\binom{12}{8} \times \binom{8}{7} \times \frac{6}{8} \times 2$$

Comment: Thank you for making an explanation that matches theirs. I think they are counting it sequentially as you have done here!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my answer is wrong, but I was thinking of this:
There are four directions: **U**p, **D**own, **L**eft and **R**ight.

In order to go from bottom left to upper right, you need 6 **U** and 6 **R**, which is a total of 12 movements.

In order to get to 14 movements, you need to take an extra step and one back, so we end up with:

7 **U**, 1 **D** and 6 **R**, or:
6 **U**, 7 **R** and 1 **L**.

The amount of ways to do this is:

$$\frac{(7 + 1 + 6)!}{7! \cdot 1! \cdot 6!} + \frac{(6 + 7 + 1)!}{6! \cdot 7! \cdot 1!}$$

The result of this seems to be 48.048, which is clearly different than the proposed 5940, so something is wrong here. It's not my reasoning (I have correctly found all the ways to travel), so it should be my calculation. Feel free to add comments, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

**Remark:** my answer is divisible by 13, which is obvious because we are talking about taking 14 steps ($13 + 1$), so I'm wondering what happened to the 13 in the correct result 5940.

Comment: You are including cases where the path retraces its steps, i.e. paths containing RL, LR, DU. or UD. The question asks for paths that do not revisit any intersection point.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: you're right, thank yo.

Comment: You would also need to eliminate the possibilities of the L coming before or after all the R's / the D coming before or after all the U's, as these would force the path outside the grid.

Comment: @A.J.: "What are the different solutions in case you are or you are not allowed to go outside of the grid?". That would make it an even more interesting question :-)